# I have a private lot parking permit but there are no spaces available, legal remedies?

Tags: contract-law, canada

I bought a parking permit for a private lot attached to my apartment but today when I came to park I found that no spaces were available. What can I do?

The parking spaces are not marked off in any way, people park where they want to.

Comment: Does the contract, or terms, guarantee that a parking space will be available?

Comment: Are there cars without the permit? If so write down the license plates and tell the owner of the lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your permit entitles you to what is says it does in the contract.

It is extremely likely that the operator explicitly does not warrant there will be parking available when you want it. If so, you have no breach and no remedy.